# NFSv4 ACL failure

Tags: mount, nfs, acl

I try to share NFSv4 from ubunto 12.04, (installed package nfs4-acl-tools) - this is my server:

```
/export/NewShareName *(rw,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,fsid=c7f7fca9-842b-80fe-bc7f-3b888dffd794)
```

From debian (my client), I try to mount that share with command:

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 10.10.149.170:/export/NewShareName /mnt/nfs4
```

Mount is successful, mount -v output from debian is:

```
10.10.149.170:/export/NewShareName on /mnt/nfs4 type nfs4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,vers=4.0,rsize=262144,wsize=262144,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.10.255.119,local_lock=none,addr=10.10.149.170)
```

While in debian (on mounted directory), I can do nfs4_getfacl and see the following:

```
messi@nas-B9-43-AA:/mnt/nfs4$ nfs4_getfacl messifile
A::OWNER@:rwatTcCy
A::GROUP@:rtcy
A::EVERYONE@:rtcy
```

But when trying to use nfs4_setfacl i get error:

```
messi@nas-B9-43-AA:/mnt/nfs4$ nfs4_setfacl -a D::EVERYONE@:rtcy messifile
Failed setxattr operation: Input/output error
messi@nas-B9-43-AA:/mnt/nfs4$
```

What am I doing wrong ??